# Ip forwarding in windows 2008

Tags: windows, iis, router, port-forwarding

I have a server in  my local LAN with a local IP and I 've deployed my web application on this server, I can see the application on local clients.

For external users I have forwarded specific port in router to the local IP address of my server.but it does not work. When I forward it to another server with windows 2003 it works properly, but with Windows 2008 server it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the firewall on the Windows 2008 server to allow connection on the web application port?  Windows 2008 has the firewall on by default and may be restricted to local subnet addresses.  Not so sure about 2003.

Comment: Yes ,I even turned off the fire wall

Comment: And ,As I said I can see my web site in local Lan,but don't know what happens when I'm going to visit the site over the internet.